# AWS Amplify Authenticator in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, oauth, aws-amplify-cli

I am using AWS Amplify and SwiftUI. When I use the standard Authenticator from amplify, it works correctly. How do I extend the Authenticator to display Google and Facebook sign-in buttons? This is some code inside a SwiftUI struct.

```
Authenticator(initialStep: .signIn, headerContent: {
                Button("Continue as guest") {
                    isGuest = true // navigate as guest
                }
                .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, alignment:.trailing)
                .padding(.trailing, 5)
            }) { _ in
                FirstView()
                    
            }
```

If I simply need to add a button in the footerContent to allow social media sign-in, what should the function be that I attach to it?

The Authenticator object is coming from [Amazon's website](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/new-amplify-swiftui-based-authenticator-component/). I added the package to my Xcode project and use it as in the code above.

My info.plist is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>myapp</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allows you to place an order verbally.</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>amazonaws.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Cardo-Italic</string>
        <string>Cardo-Regular</string>
        <string>Cardo-Bold</string>
        <string>NotoSerif-Regular</string>
        <string>NotoSerif-Italic</string>
        <string>NotoSerif-BoldItalic</string>
        <string>NotoSerif-Bold</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Is it enabled for your user pool? You can't just add it frontend wise.

Comment: I think it is. They are listed under Federated identity provider sign-in.

Comment: `signInWithWebUI` is what you need I believe- take a look at: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/signin_web_ui/q/platform/ios/

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I read a bunch in the docs and made several attempts to make this work before I posted the question. I have seen this page, but I have no idea what to do with that. One way I tried was to put a button in headerContent and call the function your suggest when the button is clicked. I run into all kinds of errors when I try to do that. If you have a simple example illustrating how to do this, I would like it if you would post an answer.

Comment: Can you please show where `Authenticator` is coming from? And which social media providers do you have? What does you `Info.plist` look like?

Comment: I added that info to the question.

Comment: Are you following all the instructions from the official amplify documentation?
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social/q/platform/ios/#prerequisites